# В htaccess после 9 параметров url`а, все следуйщии заменяются первым + инкремент

Tags: php, .htaccess, get

Извините сразу но не знаю, как правильно сформулировать вопрос. Суть дела есть условно такой url

```
http://coren/search/categ/45/sub_cat/16/minprice/0/maxprice/100/private/true/firma/true/client/true/children/true/pet/true/wifi/true
```

вардамп гета выглядит так:

```
array(20) { 
  ["cmd"]=> string(6) "search" 
  ["p"]=> string(5) "categ" 
  ["p2"]=> string(2) "45" 
  ["p3"]=> string(7) "sub_cat" 
  ["p4"]=> string(2) "16" 
  ["p5"]=> string(8) "minprice" 
  ["p6"]=> string(1) "0" 
  ["p7"]=> string(8) "maxprice" 
  ["p8"]=> string(3) "100" 
  ["p9"]=> string(7) "private" 
  ["p10"]=> string(6) "categ0" 
  ["p11"]=> string(6) "categ1" 
  ["p12"]=> string(6) "categ2" 
  ["p13"]=> string(6) "categ3" 
  ["p14"]=> string(6) "categ4" 
  ["p15"]=> string(6) "categ5" 
  ["p16"]=> string(6) "categ6" 
  ["p17"]=> string(6) "categ7" 
  ["p18"]=> string(6) "categ8" 
  ["p19"]=> string(6) "categ9" 
}
```

в htaccess прописано

```
RewriteRule ^search/([^/]*)$ /?cmd=search&p=$1 [L]

RewriteRule ^search/([^/])/([^/])$ /?cmd=search&p=$1&p2=$2 [L]

RewriteRule ^search/([^/])/([^/])/([^/]*)$ /?cmd=search&p=$1&p2=$2&p3=$3 [L]

RewriteRule ^search/([^/])/([^/])/([^/])/([^/])$ /?cmd=search&p=$1&p2=$2&p3=$3&p4=$4 [L]

RewriteRule ^search/([^/])/([^/])/([^/])/([^/])/([^/]*)$ /?cmd=search&p=$1&p2=$2&p3=$3&p4=$4&p5=$5 [L]
```

и так далее вплоть до p25

Вопрос: почему на p10 и дальше значение реальное гета заменяется на p1+инкремент Заранее спасибо, извините за не опытность и безграмотность

Comment: Думаете так читаемость текста лучше чем после моего форматирования вашего кода?

Comment: изивините, первый раз на сайте не могу понять, что вообще происходить :) по возможности верните ваше редактирование. Спасибо

Comment: Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, отметьте его как верный (галка напротив выбранного ответа).

Answer (score 1):

> RewriteRule backreferences: These are backreferences of the form $N (0 <= N <= 9). $1 to $9 provide access to the grouped parts (in parentheses) of the pattern, from the RewriteRule which is subject to the current set of RewriteCond conditions. $0 provides access to the whole string matched by that pattern.

То есть можно использовать только от `$0` до `$9` для доступа к сгруппированным частям шаблона: http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/mod_rewrite.html#RewriteCond

**UPD** Добавлю ответ на вопрос:

> почему на p10 и дальше значение реальное гета заменяется на p1+инкремент

Потому, что учитывается только первая цифра после знака `$` в `$10` для замены на сгруппированную часть (`$1`), а вторая цифра остается просто символом и дописывается после подставленной строки.